# tracking Lost bitcoin wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet

I bought bitcoin 3yrs ago (i did not know so much about it then, i was only playing with it). 
I received the bitcoin via a particular address which I still have. How can i track the BTC wallet I used via BTC address?

Answer (score 1):

The best way you can do is one of the below:

- Check your computer for the wallet file of the BTC address if it was a desktop wallet
- Check your home for any paper/computer for the private key/seed of that BTC address if it was a desktop wallet
- Check your browser history for any exchange login and try to login and check for that balance.

With just the BTC address, you cannot find the info of the BTC wallet.